# using Java Embedded Suite

Tags: java

I extracted the Oracle Java Embedded Suite to my raspberry pi.
For glassfish I only see one jar, glassfish-jes.jar.

How do I get this up and running?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? What are you expecting?

Comment: Well, if I extract glassfish, jersey, javadb to my PI, I would expect some guide on how to get things up and running. How about a hello world example? Something...

Comment: Did you try `java -jar glassfish-jes.jar` ?

Answer (score 1):

> You can run JAR packaged applications with the Java launcher (java command). The basic command is:
>
> `java -jar jar-file`

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html)